# How do you evaluate the integral $\dfrac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi x\sin(nx)dx$ and

Tags: calculus, integration

How do you evaluate the integral $$\dfrac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi x\sin(nx)dx$$

I am new to Fourier series and integration so need help here. I have no idea how to evaluate this integral. Can you do this steps by steps so I can follow and learn more?

Thank you!

PS: How do you make the integral sign larger with Latex?

Comment: An integral by parts should do the job: $u=x$ and $dv=\sin(nx)dx$.

Answer (score 5):

Set $u(x)=x$ and $v^\prime(x)=\sin(nx)$. In other words, $v(x)=-\frac 1 n \cos(nx)$.

Then the integration by parts formula is
$$\int_a^b u(x)v^\prime(x)dx=\left[u(x)v(v)\right]_a^b-\int_a^bu^\prime(x)v(x)dx$$
In other words,
$$\begin{split}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi x\sin(nx)dx &= \left[ -\frac x n\cos(nx)\right]_{-\pi}^{\pi}+\frac 1 n\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(nx)dx\\
&= -\frac {2\pi} n
\end{split}$$
That's if $n\neq 0$. For $n=0$, the integral is $0$.

Comment: Can you do it more steps so I can learn?

Comment: Done! I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have suggested, use integration by parts.

Here's an explanation:

Note that the product rule states:
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\big(u(x)\cdot v(x)\big) = u(x)\dfrac{dv(x)}{dx}+ \dfrac{du(x)}{dx}v(x)$$
If one "multiplies" both sides by $dx$, and integrate you obtain:
$$u(x)\cdot v(x) = \int u(x) \dfrac{dv(x)}{dx}dx + \int v(x)\dfrac{du(x)}{dx} dx$$
Subtracting the right term from the right hand side, we obtain:
$$u(x)v(x) - \int v(x)\dfrac{du(x)}{dx} dx = \int u(x) \dfrac{dv(x)}{dx}dx$$

The idea is to select $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ so that you can follow the pattern suggested by these equations - drastically simplifying the integral. There's even a helpful acronym for how to select the function $u(x)$. **LIPET**

**L**ogs

**I**nverse Trig

**P**olynomials

**E**xponentials

**T**rig

One would select the first of whichever functions in the acronym you'd find first - here'd you select $u(x) = x$, and $\dfrac{dv}{dx} = \sin(nx)$.

The integral is:
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x\sin(nx)dx = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}u\dfrac{dv(x)}{dx}dx = \bigg[-\dfrac{1}{n}x\cos(nx)\bigg]_{-\pi}^{\pi} - \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}-\dfrac{1}{n}\cos(nx)dx$$
$$= -\dfrac{2\pi}{n}$$

Now, if $n=0$, the whole integral is zero.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Integration by parts to  eliminate the factor $x$:
$$u=x, \quad \mathrm d v=\cos nx\,\mathrm d x.$$
whence $\;\mathrm du=\mathrm dx,\quad  v=\frac1n\sin nx$.

Next use the integration by parts formula:
$$\int_a^bu\,\mathrm dv=uv\bigg|_a^b-\int_a^b v\,\mathrm du.$$

Comment: Note the question is basically a PSQ (Problem Statement Question) which, as you likely know, is generally frowned on, including some people thinking we shouldn't usually provide answers to them. I don't down vote answers (including yours here) because of this, but I rarely up vote any answers provided to them. I recall reading in the meta section that it seems there are at least a few members here who will down vote answers provided to PSQ's. Of course, this is just my speculation in this case. However, if you see this mostly happens with your answers to PSQ's, it may be the reason.

Comment: @JohnOmielan/ I took into consideration the O.P.'s claim to be new to the subject involved, and, further, I didn't give a *full* solution – only a hint for the method.